# Keep footer for multiple activities

Tags: android, android-activity, footer

I'm creating an app which requires the footer to remain constant among various activities. That is, when animating to another activity, the footer doesn't animate with it - it stays there. Here is an example of what I mean: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EwXjdTvVXHQ&feature=related

I know it's an awesome app, but please don't forget my question ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Fragments to switch out your content, then you can keep one activity with the same footer. Fragments are backported all the way to Donut.

Comment: well, I've done a bunch of reading on fragments and managed to get activities to switch out while keeping the footer. But the activities don't allow interaction. I can click on their buttons but nothing happens. Is there something else I need to know? Here's a general picture of what I'm tring to accomplish: [http://i.imgur.com/K8Iao.jpg.](http://i.imgur.com/K8Iao.jpg) Each button corresponds to an activity. The buttons work but the activities just sit there once loaded - no interaction allowed.

Comment: ViewPager with FragmentPagerAdapter would do just that. Stop thinking that each screen has to be it's own Activity, but rather you can have groups of views as a Fragment that you swap out. Then put your logic to handle interaction inside each fragment, and allow your Activity hosting the ViewPager and footer buttons to handle the button clicks, and pass them on to the displayed fragment if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Use only one activity with footer and body in your app, switches and animates body only just like switches in activities.

Answer (score 0):

Create a dummy class that extends an Activity and add footer to it.using xml (or the sameway you would do for other activity).
And extend this class in your app wherever you want footer.